# String_Split inserts only the first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I'm trying to insert comma separated Guids into a temp table, to later check for a value using `IN` in these Guids. The following query is inserting only the first value in the table twice.

```
DECLARE @campaignids nvarchar(max) = '1DEBD122-FF1B-4E87-8812-D427ABA5D54E,FBD06A2E-24D1-4C06-B71D-B4306D8EA3BD'
DECLARE @TempCampaignIds TABLE (CampaignId uniqueidentifier) 

INSERT INTO @TempCampaignIds
SELECT CAST(@campaignids AS uniqueidentifier)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@campaignids, ',') 

SELECT CampaignId FROM @TempCampaignIds

--result  
CampaignId  
1DEBD122-FF1B-4E87-8812-D427ABA5D54E  
1DEBD122-FF1B-4E87-8812-D427ABA5D54E
```

[image]

Comment: Gordon explains the your mistake in their answer, but really this is a typographical error, you're inserting the parameter not the column returned from the function due to using the parameter name in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the value from the string:

```
INSERT INTO @TempCampaignIds (CampaignId)
    SELECT CAST(s.value AS uniqueidentifier)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@campaignids, ',') s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9c15db55e845ec28f92e6f197bca087) is a db<>fiddle.

I'm actually surprised that your code works, but SQL Server converts the first value of such a string without an error.  That doesn't seem to happen for other data types.  In fact, SQL Server appears to look at only the first 36 characters for a unique identifier.

Comment: To answer why the OP's code works, and doesn't give a conversion error, it is both expected and documented behaviour, as I explain in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65238767/2029983).

Comment: @Larnu . . . I have no doubt that it is correct and documented.  I'm just surprised that unique identifiers are treated differently from other types in this respect.    Even a conversion with a style that specifies a fixed length generates an error with extra characters at the end.  I wonder why Microsoft did this.

Comment: Some other data types do actually behaviour similarly. If you try and insert a `datetime2` into a `date`, for example, you don't get an error the time portion is simply truncated. The same is effectively true here; characters after the 36th are simply truncated when the value is converted.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I don't view that as similar at all.  I should have been clearer that I'm referring to strings.